# How to set permission to write file in centOS under root directory with php

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm trying to write file under /root/usr directory with the help of php. Php only allow me to write the files only under /home/domain/public_html/ directory.

Here I get the error 
you have only read permissions.

Comment: The permissions must be changed, or ACL added (if your OS supports them).  This is a system issue, not Apache-PHP per say.  Nothing in PHP will allow you to create files if the OS does not allow it.